# llama-index.ts - not all chunks in the pipeline are embedded (embeddings:undefined are returned)

Tags: llama-index, openaiembeddings

i run into a problem where embeddings are undefined after just 2 runs on the pipeline. I'm using the codes from this documentation: https://ts.llamaindex.ai/api/classes/OpenAIEmbedding

here is the code

```
const { Document, VectorStoreIndex, IngestionPipeline, SimpleNodeParser, OpenAIEmbedding } = require("llamaindex");

const processDocuments = async (text) => {
    // Create Document object with essay
    try{
        const document = new Document({ text: text });
        // console.log('this are the Documents: "', document) - this is fine
        const pipeline = new IngestionPipeline({
            transformations: [
            new SimpleNodeParser({ chunkSize: 1024, chunkOverlap: 20 }),
            new OpenAIEmbedding(),
            ],
      });
    // run the pipeline
    const nodes = await pipeline.run({ documents: [document] }); 
    // console.log('this are the Nodes: "', nodes) - this is where i found that the embeddings are undefined
    // Create an index from the chunks
    const index = VectorStoreIndex.fromDocuments(nodes.documents);
    console.log('this are the index: "', index) - this runs into an error, will append below
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Something wrong while processing the document: ', error);
        throw error;
    }
};
    
module.exports = {processDocuments}
error from console.log('this are the index: "', index)
```

this is the error i face. When i digged deeper, it was due to some embeddings being undefined.

```
this are the index: " Promise { <pending> }
Error indexing text:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')
```

I tried to manually look for each chunk where embedding == undefined. Conceptually, I think this is wrong as it has to be consisted with respect to the whole documents.

I have also tried the following

1. vary the parameters of OpenAIEmbedding (maxRetries, timeout, embedBatchSize) but it still produces the same results (embed the first 2 chunks, and leave the rest out)
2. when I use a shorter text file, if it is within 2 chunks, i can embed the whole document

Answer (score 0):

Was released a new version with a bug fix for this v1.11.0, you can check it update to the latest version